# Sequence of ribosomal RNA

Tags: dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing, ribosome

Is it possible to sequence rRNA directly, that is, using the ribosome rather than the DNA from the nucleus? For example, this paper, [Complete nucleotide sequence of a 16s rRNA gene from E. coli](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC336208/),  suggests that it uses DNA to find the sequence. Would it be possible to isolate the rRNA and derive the sequence from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unequivocally, YES.

Before DNA sequencing was used to deduce the sequence of cloned or reverse-transcribed RNA molecules, slower and more cumbersome direct sequencing of RNA was performed using the method of Sanger *et al.*  [(Sanger, F., Brownlee, G. G. and Barrel B. G. (1965) J. Mol. Biol. **13**, pp. 373–398)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283665801048). This used ribonucleases in a manner somewhat similar to pre-Edmann protein sequencing.

Because of its abundance and ease of purification ribosomal RNA was a suitable species for this approach, and Carbon *et al* reported the complete sequence of *E. coli* 16S rRNA in [1978 (Carbon P., Ehresmann C., Ehresmann, B. and Ebel J.P. (1978) FEBS Letters **94**, pp. 152-156)](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0014579378809260/1-s2.0-0014579378809260-main.pdf?_tid=e15c1e6f-cce2-4907-8e8e-c0bb59987170&acdnat=1548022336_a89b99491a1d4422e8ccd7d563085053).

Sigh! How little do modern molecular biologists know about the history of their subject.

Comment: In addition to that most people doing (m)RNA/transcriptome sequencing nowadays actually *worry* about sequencing rRNA - there is so much more rRNA in cells that it needs to be thoroughly removed before you can even sequence any other RNA species.